# Trouble understanding negation of definition of convergent sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, logic, quantifiers

Definition of convergent sequence:
$$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb R: \forall n \in \mathbb N \ (n \ge N \implies d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon)$$

I found the negation to be:
$$\exists \varepsilon > 0, \forall N \in \mathbb R: \exists n \in \mathbb N \ (n \ge N \land d(x_n, x) \ge \varepsilon)$$

However, I am having trouble understanding what is meant by $(n \ge N \land d(x_n, x) \ge \varepsilon)$. Specifically, the conjunction part. ($\land$)

What does it mean when we say ($n \ge N$ and $d(x_n, x) \ge \varepsilon$)?

Answer (score 1):

Say it aloud.
"There is some n where n is greater than N and the distance from $x_n$ to $x$ is greater than epsilon."

Even though N may be large, there is some $x_n$ has moved away from the proposed limit point by more than a minimal amount.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase

- for all $N \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge \mathbb{R}$ and BLAH$(n)$

can be understood more colloquially as

- BLAH$(n)$ is true for arbitrarily large natural numbers $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Another equivalent way to express it is by saying

- There is a sequence of natural numbers $n_i \to +\infty$ such that BLAH$(n_i)$ is true for all $i$.

So, the negation of convergent sequence could be expressed in words as

- there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $d(x_n,x) \ge \epsilon$ for arbitrarily large $n$

or as

- there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence of natural numbers $n_i \to +\infty$ such that $d(x_{n_i},x) \ge \epsilon$ for all $i$.